# OSmetrics in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

We get data in Kibana, but we can't make any sense of it. We want to visualize the OS metrics in Kibana, but I don't seem to get them in percentages and I want them to update automatically.

We are using the full elkstack with metricbeat and we want the data to go through logstash to keep it more future proof.

Comment: can you share your mapping and sample data and query that you using

Comment: How do you mean mapping? And we don't use a query, we just look in the discovery and then try to combine tags and visualize them.

Comment: what all thing you did yet can you tell me

Comment: For example, i tried to look for CPU data via Kibana, I selected those categories and tried to visualize them, but the values don't say anything.

Comment: how u get your cpu data and have you saved that into Elasticsearch

Comment: With metricbeat, and yes they are saved in elasticsearch. The data gets send trough the elkstack pipeline

Comment: can you share me few thing  run this in and share result with me kibana GET /_cat/indices